# PHP: multilingual website on subdomains w/o many copies of public_html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, internationalization, subdomain

I have a multilingual (11 languages) website. Right now it works chooses language using 'language' get parameter or a cookie. Now I want to use subdomains instead of cookies and get parameter. But I do not want to make 11 complete copies of website (engine and some static stuff) for each subdomain. Is it possible to place some php and htaccess code (a very little piece) into each subdomain's root catalog, so only one copy of website's engine and stuff will be used by 11 subdomains. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say to configure your Apache to point all your [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) to the same folder, then use [$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to figure out what subdomain was requested.

Comment: How can I configure Apache to point all virtual hosts to the same folder? can you write the code please :)

Comment: It's not in code exactly, it's in the Apache configuration file.  Please see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

you will not have much choice than to determine the chosen language somehow. I like aSeptik's idea best so far, but in my applications, I rather use the [accept-language](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header) http-header from the browser to determine the default language of the user and use a session (so cookies or POST-Parameters again) to save a different language choice.

Comment: I need all versions of website indexed by search engines. This method would not be useful.